# json decode key types

Tags: json, go

I want to decode a big set of data from a (static-schema) json file. The file contains exclusively numeric data, and keys are all integers. I know how to decode this json into a struct containing fields of `map[string]int` or `map[string]float32` using json.Unmarshal. But I have no interest in string keys, I'd need to convert them to int somehow.

So what I'd like to know is:

1. Is there a way to achieve this, .ie getting a struct containing fields of map[int]float32 type directly from decoding,
2. Otherwise how to achieve this after decoding, in a memory efficient manner ?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: run your json file through http://jsonlint.com/ to see how it feels about your "json".

Comment: `Results
Valid JSON.`
Did I ever mention I had a problem with my json file ?

Comment: No, but using numbers as keys in a json file is invalid and would result in most json tools automatically converting them to strings.  You might be able to fork the encoding/json package and make it do what you want...but in any case, my vote went for the @ANisus's (correct) answer below

Comment: ok. My keys are in double quotes actually (although still being numeric values), so the json is valid. If there no other solution than @ANsius' I will do that way. But during the conversion that makes twice the data in memory, and that's what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I added an answer, but you'll have to unmarshal it yourself, there's no built in way to do what you're looking to do.

Comment: @y__b__y: During the marshal process you will still have the data twice in memory: as raw json and as a map. This remains even if your write your on Unmarshaller.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [JSON format](http://www.json.org) only specifies key/value objects with string keys. Because of this, the `encoding/json` package only supports string keys as well.

The `json/encoding` documentation states:

> bool, for JSON booleans
>   float64, for JSON numbers
>   string, for JSON strings
>   []interface{}, for JSON arrays
>   map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
>   nil for JSON null

If you want to use `encoding/json` package and move it over to a map[int]float64, you can do the following (works with float32 as well):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    a := map[string]float64{"1":1, "2":4, "3":9, "5":25}
    b := make(map[int]float64, len(a))

    for k,v := range a {
        if i, err := strconv.Atoi(k); err == nil {
            b[i] = v
        } else {
            // A non integer key
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", b)
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/dEMFIzoK95)

Answer (score 0):

The `encoding/json` package includes an interface `Unmarshaler` which has a single method: `UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error`.

If you're feeling brave you *could* implement that for the following:

```
type IntToFloat map[int]float32

func (itf *IntToFloat) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if itf == nil {
        return errors.New("Unmarshalling JSON for a null IntToFload")
    }
    // MAGIC Goes here.
    return nil
}
```

**EDIT**

Note: http://golang.org/src/pkg/encoding/json/decode.go?s=2221:2269#L53 is where the std library version of Unmarshal comes from.

http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler is where the interface referenced above comes from.

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! I'm not sure I'm skilled enough with go right now to use this solution though ^^